# Regex for two or three character string of which 0 or 1 may be a digit

Tags: regex

What is a regex to match a string that is either two or three characters long, of which at most one character is a digit and the rest are letters?

Examples of matching input:

```
T4
T4T
4TT
TT
```

Examples of non-matching input:

```
T
T44
T4TT
_4_
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead to assert max 1 digit:

```
^(?!.*\d.*\d)[^\W_]{2,3}$
```

Explanation:

- `(?!.*\d.*\d)` means "assert that after this point there is **not** 2 digits"
- `\W` means "a non-word character" - a "word character" is any letter, digit or the underscore. This is the opposite of `\w`, which means "a word character". `\W` is the same as `[^\w]`
- `[^\W_]` means "neither a non-word character nor an underscore"  It is identical to `[0-9a-zA-Z]`, but shorter to write
- `{2,3}` means "between 2 and 3 (inclusive) of the previous term"

I'm pretty sure this is the shortest solution.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/ADC28hWztD) with your test cases.

Comment: @pythonicmetaphor I prefer rubular over all other regex testers because it's clear, complete and easy to use, but mainly because it's the only one the works on my iPhone, which is the device I use for most for posting on stackoverflow. Regex101 etc fail totally on an iPhone - you can't use them at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex with [positive look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
/^(?=[a-z\d]{2,3}$)[a-z]{0,3}\d?[a-z]{0,3}$/i
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/nN4mC9/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 1):

Using negative lookahead you can use this regex:

```
^(?![a-zA-Z]*\d+[a-zA-Z]*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{2,3}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xW0fI1/1)

- `(?![a-zA-Z]*\d+[a-zA-Z]*\d)` is negative lookahead to fail the match if there are more than 1 digit in input
- `[a-zA-Z\d]{2,3}` will match 2 or 3 characters that consist of letters and digits.